# Searching a JSON file for a specific value, python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

[image]

I have a list of device ID's, and I'd like to search my JSON for a specific value of the `id`, to get the `name`.

The data that is now is JSON format used to be in XML format, for which I used to do this:

```
device = xml.find("devices/device[@id=\'%s\']" %someDeviceID)
deviceName = device.attrib['name']
```

--

So far based on answers online I have managed to search the JSON for a `jey`, but I haven't yet managed to search for a `value`.

Comment: `data['devices'][someDeviceId]`. Parse it with `data = json.loads(...)` before if you need. You owe me a beer. ;)

Comment: You can `import json` and use `json.loads(open(filename, 'r').read())` to read this file into a python object, then do what @freakish posted above. And you owe him a beer. ETA: Use `data['devices'].get('someDeviceId')` if you're not sure if 'someDeviceId` exists.

Comment: @freakish When I do <code>data['devices']</code> I get <code>[{u'id' : u'7DD88039CFE09C3', u'name' : u'Watchdog 15 (Internal)'}, {u'id': u'788B5635DC2EBCD2', u'name': u'Smoke Alarms'}, ... }] </code> etc.

Comment: And if I try to do <code> data['devices']["788B5635DC2EBCD2"]</code> or similar it tells me that I need to put integers not strings.

Comment: @pault It says list has no attribure get.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Ah, `devices` is an array. Fair enough. Then you have to search it, my friend. Either convert it to a dict (assuming ids are unique) or search linearly: `next(dev for dev in data['devices'] if dev['id'] == someId)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally to read a json file I use the [jsondatabase module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsondatabase). Using this module I would use the following code

```
from jsondb.db import Database 

db = Database('PATH/TO/YOUR/JSON/FILE')
for device in db['devices']:
    if device['id'] == 'SEARCHEDID':
        print(device['name'])
```

Of course when your json is online you could scrape it with the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and then parse it to the jsondatabase module

Comment: Yes it does. If you have multiple of the same ID's and you want all of them, you could add "pass" under the print line

Comment: use list comprehension